# LTC4040 Battery Backup Power Manager

Tags: charging, linear

I'm reading the datasheet but not sure if battery charger, charge the battery up to natural value 4.1 Volts, using the lowest V input threshold 3,5V.
A typical application says 4,5v but can the IC charge the battery in natural charging mode (4,1V) using as input a voltage low as 3,5V?

From the Datasheet:

> "Differential Undervoltage Lockout. An undervoltage lockout circuit
>   monitors the differential voltage between VSYS and BAT and shuts off
>   the charger if the BAT voltage reaches within 50mV of the VSYS
>   voltage. Charging does not resume until this difference increases to
>   145mV."

As it says, if input voltage is 3,5V then my battery charging up to 3,5V. Right?

[TLC4040](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4040)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4040fa.pdf), the VIN to BAT path is a buck (step down) converter, and the BAT to VSYS path is a boost (step up) converter.  See page 13 for the description of the buck-mode battery charger.  See page 15 for the description of the boost-mode powering of the system via the battery.

The buck mode charger will not be able to charge the battery if the input voltage is less than the battery voltage.  So your first question:

> A typical application says 4,5v but can the IC charge the battery in natural charging mode (4,1V) using as input a voltage low as 3,5V?

The answer is no.  If the input voltage is 3.5V, it will not charge the battery to 4.1V.  I can't see any specifications that would provide a "minimum input voltage" for the buck-mode charger to charge to 4.1V, besides the "typical application circuit" calling out a 4.22V PFI threshold.  Although this suggests a 4.22V minimum voltage, targeting a 4.5V typical would be appropriate.  The specifications to look for would be "maximum duty cycle" for the buck converter, but this is not listed.  I would treat 4.22V as the minimum, or ask a factory representative for clarification based on your application.

For your second question:

> As it says, if input voltage is 3,5V then my battery charging up to 3,5V. Right?

The answer is no.  The voltage provided at the PFI input determines when the chip is in buck-mode (charging) or boost-mode (backing up VSYS with the battery); see the block diagram on page 12.

When PFI is > 1.19V, the LTC4040 passes VIN to VSYS, and charges the battery.
When PFI is < 1.19V, the LTC4040 ignores VIN, and boosts VBAT to VSYS to power the system.

There is a tolerance to apply to PFI (PFI Input Threshold and PFI Input Hysteresis on page 4).

Comment: And for what reason minimum voltage specified at 3,5V and not equal to PFI threshold? If my input voltage it's less than battery charging voltage, the battery would not charging?

Comment: From when the PFI threshold it's 1,19V i assume that minimum input voltage it's at the same level: 1,19V. This mean, connect input voltage to PFI without voltage divider

Comment: How can i get more information about minimum input voltage for natural battery charging?

Comment: I consider that the 3,5V as minimum input voltage it's for the other chemistry, LiFePO4 batteries which have 3,2V nominal voltage value.

Comment: @MrBit To charge the battery, the chip only has a buck (step-down) converter.  Which means you can only charge up to as high as the input voltage, assuming the buck converter can run at 100% duty cycle (which it probably can't).  As I said in my answer, you would need to ask a factory representative to get better information on the actual Vin(min) given a particular battery chemistry/voltage; the specifications do not provide sufficient information.

Comment: Yes of course but I wonder, why minimum voltage input it's less than battery charging value (4,1v for liion batteries) and as I looking, lifepo4 batteries charging with CV 3,5V which is the minimum input of the chip, but this means that with one lifepo4 battery in 3,5v input voltage buck step down does not have decrease the voltage.it is normal?

Comment: How can I contact with factory representative?

Comment: http://www.linear.com/contact/

Comment: I sent the mail and I'm still waiting for reply